# C++ tutorial and full API Specification the same as Java has?

Tags: c++, java

Are there resources for C++ which would be like Java has?

Like full tutorial `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial`

and like full API Specification `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html`

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) help?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the C++ standard library is part of the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011). That standard has to be purchased, but recent drafts that only minimally differ from the official standard are available on the homepage of the [C++ working group](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/).

Note that the standard is quite terse. A more beginner-friendly introduction to the C++ standard library was [written by Nicolai Josuttis](http://www.amazon.de/The-Standard-Library-Tutorial-Reference/dp/0321623215).

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a language not an API there is a specification for C++ but there is no such thing as an API.

There is a ISO standard for C++ and a book: http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470846747.html

There are many books on the standard library that details the idiomatic usage of STL and the new C++11 standard adopts many Boost libraries such as smart pointers.

Josuttis' book: http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/, interestingly there is a second edition which covers C++11 which I wasn't aware of.

There are also many Boost books which you can google for, I would recommend the following: http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Boost-Libraries-Boris-Schaling/dp/0982219199/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1336925944&sr=8-5

and http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beyond-Standard-Library-Introduction-Boost/dp/0321133544/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1336925944&sr=8-6

Any APIs you will see will be framework and OS specific, the standard library does not cover this like JAVA does unfortunately.

Comment: The c++ standard actually defines quite a lot of the API..

Comment: The C++ standard defines both the language and the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I know this [site](http://www.cplusplus.com/). I agree that there is no API regarding C++. This language doesn't have the a.b.c.d() form that Java has. However this site is very helpful if you knwo what to look for